# Easiest well-known video compression codec that can be coded from scratch

Tags: video, windows-phone-8, codec

I'm searching for a video format that would be compatible both with most media website like flickr and with Windows Phone 8.

WP8 support: MP3, WMA, WMA, 3GP, 3G2, AMR, 3GP, 3G2, MP4, M4A, MPR, AAC, 3GP, 3G2, MP4, M4A, AAC, 3GP, 3G2, MP4, M4A, AAC

I've read several documentation about media encoding on Windows Phone to find that nothing can turn images into video. Most WP apps are using online Azure services to encode medias, because of CPU concerns, I guess.

I'm currently developing an application where I need to convert frames to video "on the fly". Saving it as an AVI would be the simplest - though space consuming - way to achieve it. But I fear it won't be compatible on both side.

To summarize, what I'm doing is capturing video with `VideoSink`, receiving frames with `OnSample`, and re-encoding it. I'm just searching the simplest codec to encode it. Or "coder", since I won't decode it.

Are there some codecs, either lossless or non-lossless, that can easily be adapted into C# without any C++ or native DLL?

Comment: There's a whole universe of video codecs out there (my multimedia friends and I have catalogued well over 200 different codecs). The first thing you need to nail down is requirements-- what exactly are you hoping to achieve? Are you trying to make a Windows Phone app that generates videos and is able to upload those videos to Flickr? Or a PC app that creates videos and can stream them to a Windows Phone or upload to Flickr?

Comment: Actually, I'm using a VideoSink, thus, I receive an RGB pixel array each time OnSample is called. I want this flow to be reconverted to a video. I can code the codec, but knowing I'll reinvent the wheel, I want this wheel to be simple. Just like Jules Cesar's wood wheels. Btw, I changed Flickr to Youtube. Flickr can't handle ogg. So open source fails from start with flickr.

Comment: I guess lossless/zip codecs are simpler than non-lossless codecs.

Comment: Why couldn't you find an implementation of the video codec you are interested in in C/C++ and natively invoke it from C# side?

Comment: I guess that's what I'll end up doing. There is 0 project or examples of transcoder / encoder for WP. I know that some people from the VLC/ffmpeg team will -MAYBE- come with something in the next months. But right now, I can't see nothing on Silverlight / RT / Windows Phone.